# Як перекласти словосполучення "video abstracts"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, запозичені-слова, словосполучення

Зіткнулась із необхідністю перекласти з англійської словосполучення "**video abstracts**".

Значення слова "**abstract**" знайшла у [Thesaurus Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/abstract?s=t):

> noun
>
> 6. **a summary of a text, scientific article, document, speech, etc.; epitome.**
> 7. something that concentrates in itself the essential qualities of anything more extensive or more general, or of several things;
>    essence.
> 8. an idea or term considered apart from some material basis or object.
> 9. an abstract work of art.

Іншими словами, це можна перекласти словом "**теза**", особливо, якщо вживається у наукових текстах (як у моєму випадку).

Тобто найточнішним перекладом даного словосполучення "video abstracts", на мою думку,буде "**відео-тези**".

В українській мові це слово ще не набуло широкого вжитку, тому виникають складнощі із його перекладом і написанням.

Мої варіанти:

відеотеза;

відео-теза;

відео теза.

*Тож який переклад словосполучення "video abstracts" слід вважати правильним?*

Comment: Цьікава нитка: [video abstracts](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_abstract) → [abstract](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_(summary)) → [автореферат](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Автореферат). Там є згадка про _тезу_, отже паньі думка слушна. Залишилосьа [чимось](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=abstract&highlight=on) підкріпити, бо Вікі не є ӝерелом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Video abstract** — це відео на кшталт презентації, зазвичай не більше 5 хвилин,  яке допомагає глядачеві швидко ознайомитись з науковим документом, науковою статтею, дисертацією чи оглядом: швидко з'ясувати мету та результати даного дослідження. Детальніше [тут](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_abstract).

В письмовій формі такий короткий виклад змісту називається — **анотація**.

Отож, як на мене, варто розглянути варіант перекладу — **відео-анотація**.

Comment: Те саме хотів сказати. Лише додати пару джерел щодо «abstract → анотація»: [1](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=abstract&dicts=2&main_only=on), [2](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=abstract&dicts=4&main_only=on).